# Two separate solutions for UI and API

Tags: angular, visual-studio, api

I have an out of box question not technical to get some solution.

I have seen in many places developers are creating a separate project of Angular application using Visual Studio Code and separate project for the .NET Core Web API application using Visual Studio 2019 IDE.

I've also seen in some places where there is only one solution for .NET Core and we also have the Angular application as one of the projects in the same Visual Studio solution. One advantage I understand is that it is easy to debug the API code from the front end while the back-end API code is kept running.

However which one is good way to create a solution when we have Angular in front end and Web Api in the backend and why. Sorry I am new to Angular so trying to understand this difference. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The way you saw (2 separate project one in VS code for angular and one in Visual Studio for .NET CORE) is absolutely correct.

There are many reasons:

1 - Vscode is one of the best editor for front end development and is plenty of angular plugins

2 - visual Studio. is the best IDE for .NET and .NET core projects with a beatiful intellisense and a lot of features you'll not find in any other IDE ..  now you can use it also on MAC (`https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/it/vs/mac/`) .. but for front end it is not good as vscode

3 - you can work only on the front end or only on the back end without need to load all your projects.

4 - if you need to work on both and debug all the stack you can do it without any problems (just enable CORS on the back end)

youn can do it by put this code in your startupl.cs file in `configureService` method put

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        //builder.WithOrigins("https://yoursite.com",
                        //    "https://stage.yoursite.com",
                        //     
                        //    "https://www.yoursite.com");
                        builder
                                                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials()
                        .WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition")
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                    });
            });
```

then in your `Configure` method

```
 app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins"); //<-- USE IT
            app.UseAuthentication();
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks that was real good, Just one query how to achieve this and where these chnage needs to be done.Your last point # 4
- if you need to work on both and debug all the stack you can do it without any problems (just enable CORS on the back end)

Comment: check  the edit for how configure cors for EVERYONe (commented for specific site in prod)